# Python Flask DNS server/proxy for blogging platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, dns

I'm writing my blogging platform on Flask, and looking at the experience of others noticed the opportunity to bind to your blog domain. I want to implement this on my platform, but do not know how. On other sites generate a proxy-link to bind by DNS, and I wonder if it is possible to do this on Flask

[image]
*Example on bearblog.dev*

[image]
*Example on Tumblr*

Comment: I imagine it's achieved using a custom ingress that does the translation of the domain name to blog content. When you get a request to your servers there will be a host header listing the full path including the domain-name of the site as entered in the browser url bar. The site would have a mapping of which domain-names point to which blogs in order to locate the correct content. Not sure how https would be achieved in this setup tho, as your server would need to obtain the certificate associated with the domain-name.

Comment: Found some notes on how github is doing this for github pages. Seems like a good reference. https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https#troubleshooting-certificate-provisioning-certificate-not-yet-created-error

Comment: [@flakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3280538/flakes) Hmm, sounds interesting, thanks for the tip. Searching a bit on google I found libraries which can generate Lets Encrypt certificates for own domains by code and with nslookup I can check domain connectivity, after adding it to the database. But then the next question arises: how to dynamically connect these domains and certificates. In similar questions suggest to use traefik

Comment: Started looking again and found a great article that goes into more detail about how they made this possible. https://bart.degoe.de/github-pages-and-lets-encrypt/ and https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/ . Once a user configures the DNS of their domain name to point to your sever, you can use the address to complete the CSR and obtain an HTTPS certificate. Having the domain name point to your server allows you to prove to the CA that you own the domain name and therefore are allowed to create SSL certificates for it. traefik or nginx are both good options for defining ingresses.

Comment: @flakes Thank you for the articles, I will go study them now!